# Is there a way to run request again from MVC filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to run request again from MVC exception filter?

I'd like to call the request again when I'm handling the exception in exception filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose we have the following action and we have defined a custom exception filter as shown below. Now this action will generate error if the id is not provided or a string value is provided to the id.

```
[CustomExceptionFilter]
public string Welcome(int id)
{
    return id.ToString();
}
```

Now as the action throws error. The following exception filter will handle the rest of the situation. What I have done here in this exception filter is that this will pick the controller name and action name from the RouteData, generate a random value and redirect back to this action.

This is a mere example that came to my mind, of course you can try different things with it.

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)

    {
        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            var rd = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
            string controllerName = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
            string actionName = rd.GetRequiredString("action");

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult($"/{controllerName}/{actionName}/{ new Random().Next(100, 200) }");
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```